# how to follow a windows shortcut to a subdir in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, shortcut-file

I have a subdir with a shortcut file in it, let's say it's "shortcut.lnk".
and this item is pointing to some other location. when clicking on it in windows explorer the target subdir pops up.

How can I deal with that item using cmd.exe?
How can I follow that shortcut using cmd.exe?

I probably don't want to add any third-party software but rather would like to stick and solve this with windows standard tools for portability reasons.

Comment: What do you mean with *"follow"*?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that, although if you type the shortcut file you will probably be able to figure out what the path is.

Comment: probably the file extension can give me a hint that it's a shortcut.

(the shortcut file is definitely a file not a subdir as it has a size and the file system internal 'd' attribute is not set. attrib command lists only files unless otherwise instructed or dir name is given. 'if' does not know about directorys. maybe a simple 'cd' will raise an error code.)

doing a 'type' on such a file is a problem because it's a binary file - and only a human can guess from the results if some sub-sequence is an ASCII string or a wide-char string or something else.

managing shortcuts on command line...

Comment: there is much about creating shortcuts: http://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd
maybe some of the methods have an option for querying or dumping the contents of such a shortcut so that certain values can be used in a script.

Comment: the external tool NTFSLinkView from NirSoft might offer some of the needed functionality for the "dump *.lnk" step even on the command line. it's an external tool. no idea if there is something equivalent in the system.
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html

Comment: virtually stroked out the prior comment! the tool is not about shortcut but about NTFS symlinks. --- at http://optimumx.com there is a tool called shortcut.exe that deals with the target as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

good old VBS seems to be the key for an evidently simple, short and on-board solution:

```
@echo off
Set Shortcut=%~1

echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>DecodeShortCut.vbs
echo set Lnk = WshShell.CreateShortcut(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0))>>DecodeShortCut.vbs
echo wscript.Echo Lnk.TargetPath>>DecodeShortCut.vbs

set vbscript=cscript //nologo DecodeShortCut.vbs
For /f "delims=" %%T in ( ' %vbscript% "%Shortcut%" ' ) do set target=%%T

del DecodeShortCut.vbs

Echo Shortcut %shortcut%
Echo Target   "%target%"
```

Comment: identical/adapted from this source: http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php/topic,80659.15.html?PHPSESSID=1b5da4ff4167db726b46268059a1adf8

Comment: inserting a "setlocal" as the second line
and replacing the two trailing echos with this:
---
    cd "%target%"
    pushd "%target%"
    endlocal
    popd
---
will allow to form an alternate to the "cd" command. e.g. calling it "go.cmd"